# Activity flow when redirecting from one to another

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have N number of activities, in which `Login` is root and `Intent.MAIN` subject.

My problem is that, `onResume`-ing, if a check is passed, I redirect from `Login` to `User` launching a simple Intent, but this messes up the BackStack, in a kind-of viral loop.

I've read about `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` et all, but I've not achieved anything with it.

My desired activity flow would be:

- Normal flow: `Login` -- *if already logged (onResume check)* -> `Main` -> `...` (others)
- Back button flow: `...` (others) -> `Main` -> HomeScreen

EDIT: Here are some code snippets: http://pastebin.com/PHQTn4DT

Comment: finish the login activity when you redirect the user to the Main activity

Comment: Such a silly oversight from me! Thanks!